# count the number of files older that 6 months

Tags: c#

I want to write a code to return the number (count) of the files older than 6 months.

I have the script below that returns all the files

any help would be much appreciated

code below

```
// check the number of file in the CPS directory on S drive
private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        {
        }

        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"S:\CPS Papers\"); // @"S:\CPS Papers\" C:\test\

        this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(files);
        textBox1.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at FileInfo.CreationTime (assuming that's what you're interested in). LINQ will be useful to you too.

Comment: You will ultimately want to get a `FileInfo` object representing the files you're comparing. Currently, you have just the path to the file.

Comment: A way would be to create a for each loop for your array and create a FileInfo object(constructor takes file path as argument). Then you will check the CreationTime as Jon Skeet says or the other DateTimes according to what you need..

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"S:\CPS Papers\")
    .Select(f => new FileInfo(f))
    .Where(info => info.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6))
    .Select(info => info.Name);
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I will try it today. :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a data structure

```
public class FileInfo 
{
    // .. member declaring age of a file :D (lets say Age)
}
```

If you manage to get a collection of File instances (files) you could use a linq expression:

```
var result = from file in files where file.Age > 6 select file;
```

Comment: This FileInfo class already exists. Why not use the System.IO stuff that already does this?